# Is it possible to auto-populate quantity field value from a number field value or value from nested forms merge tags?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to auto-populate the quantity field based on the total selected checkboxes from my nested forms.

Using Gravity Forms checkbox count:https://gist.github.com/spivurno/a14ef4a18f57d0c67811e1b4d8791781 
 ,I already created a merge tags that I can calculate the total selected checkboxes and put this value into a number field in the parent form. This is my merge tag: {Add a Location:25:sum=4}

Now I'm trying to apply this value in the quantity field in the main form. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one of our plugins is super useful when wanting to copy the value of one field to another. It's called Gravity Forms Copy Cat:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-copy-cat/

Comment: David, is it possible to copy from a number field to a quantity field?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. :)